# can't load csv file in python3 with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataset

Hi guys I don't know why but pandas really can't manage to load my csv file in my python code. The file is in the same folder of my python project, I'm working with tensorflow, theano, pandas, numpy and matplotlib libraries. 
It's been 2 hrs and I tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling once again using the pip3 commands. I uninstalled tensorflow, pandas, theano, numpy, and even python2 and python3. Nothing. I also updated and upgraded my linux distro. useless.

this is the error I keep getting when I execute the part of my code in the Spyder3 internal terminal:

```
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-610b2f33ea04>", line 1, in <module>
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 709, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 449, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1049, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 402, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 718, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source

FileNotFoundError: File b'Churn_Modelling.csv' does not exist
```

And this is the freaking line of code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
```

What is wrong with it guys?? I also tried to rename it.

Comment: I am confused. Are you using `read_csv` or `load_csv` ?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: What is the output of os.listdir(os.getcwd())?  Do you see the file listed there?

Comment: Harv Ipan sorry you're right, I'm using "read_cvs" I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is what it is `FileNotFoundError: File b'Churn_Modelling.csv' does not exist`. If the file exists, then it is not in the same working directory of your python script.

I would try printing the current working directory to check whether python is looking for the file in the correct directory.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Alternatively, instead of importing the file using a relative path (e.g., `Churn_Modelling.csv`), you could use an absolute path

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file/Churn_Modelling.csv')
```

Also, be mindful that in POSIX systems (e.g., Linux / Mac), the file name is case sensitive (i.e., `Churn_Modelling` is not the same as `churn_modelling`).

Comment: ok I did what you said sir and the output is "/root" . But why? I have the py file in specific subfolders in my Desktop, I will try putting the csv file in the root folder or using the relative path (even tho I've already tried that)

Comment: You are probably running the script from a service. I would try an absolute instead of moving the file to `/root`.